# How to solve inconsistent equation dimensions in Mathematica

Tags: visualization, wolfram-mathematica, equation, pde, heat

Using the heat equation and Neumann Values in mathematica I've been trying to visualise heat diversions in 2D. The code used is here :
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"]
Clear["Global`*"]

(*Define the spatial domain as a square[0,1] x[0,1]*)
domain = Rectangle[{0, 0}, {1, 1}];

(*Create a mesh for the 2D spatial domain*)
mesh = ToElementMesh[domain, "MaxCellMeasure" -> 0.01];

(*Define your temperature distribution at t=0 as an interpolation 

function*)
fI = Interpolation[
Flatten[Table[{{x, y}, 20}, {x, 0, 1, 0.1}, {y, 0, 1, 0.1}], 1]];

(*Define the heat conduction equation in 2D*)
eqn = D[T[t, x, y], t] - Laplacian[T[t, x, y], {x, y}] == 0;

(*Set initial condition*)
IC = T[0, x, y] == 20;

(*Set up Neumann boundary conditions to simulate insulation in 2D 

using NeumannValue*)
BC = {NeumannValue[0, True]};

NDSolve[{eqn == BC, IC}, T, {t, 0, 20}, {x, y} [Element] mesh]

But I keep getting the same error : [error message obtained while running the program on the latest version of Mathematica](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2PQCe.png)

I've tried to remove the {} around the NeumannValue as I assume it's causing the error but I only obtain a singular matrix which can't solve the equation. Even Chat-GPT crashed while trying to explain the error. All help is appreciated !